# Bootstrap modal popup form with cancel and submit buttons, no matter which button clicked the form submits

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to solve an issue I have with a bootstrap modal popup. I have two buttons within the form, one to cancel and one to submit the form.
If I click on the cancel button the form still gets submitted.

My form

```
<form  name="DeleteConferenceBooking" id="Conference_Delete" method="post" autocomplete="off"  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
<input name="RecordID" type="text" id="ConfDeleteRecordID">
<button type="button" class="tn btn-warning-edit btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary-edit btn-xs submit-button">Continue</button>
</form>
```

My jQuery submit code

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $('#Conference_Delete').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#open_delete_conference_booking_data_modal').toggle();
    var recordid = $('#ConfDeleteRecordID').val();
    console.log("CONFERENCE DELETE RECORDID",recordid);
    var form = this;
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("RecordID", recordid);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'conf_bookings_delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
          var result = JSON.stringify(data); 
          result = JSON.parse(result);
          console.log("RESULT", result);
          $("#open_delete_conference_booking_data_modal").modal('hide');
          $("#open_edit_data_modal").modal('hide');
          $('#userTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    }); 
  });   
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try to use sweet alert 2

Comment: You have the on click handler attached to the whole modal. it will be triggered no matter where you will click on the modal.

Comment: @Nawed Khan Hi and thanks for your reply, how should I be laying out my code so that the click handler does not attach to the whole modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the event to submit instead of click.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $('#Conference_Delete').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#open_delete_conference_booking_data_modal').toggle();
    var recordid = $('#ConfDeleteRecordID').val();
    console.log("CONFERENCE DELETE RECORDID",recordid);
    var form = this;
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("RecordID", recordid);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'conf_bookings_delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
          var result = JSON.stringify(data); 
          result = JSON.parse(result);
          console.log("RESULT", result);
          $("#open_delete_conference_booking_data_modal").modal('hide');
          $("#open_edit_data_modal").modal('hide');
          $('#userTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    }); 
  });   
});
```

Comment: why I did not spot that I don't know. Many thanks for looking at the issue.